# BufferedReader.readLine() Creating threads()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to make a server that can have multiple users, im only creating 2 Threads but my BufferedReader.readLine() seems to be making multiple threads and causing a OutOfMemory Exception, I dont see why its doing this?

Function causing Exception:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Username = Input.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        disconnect();
    }
    String lastInput = null;
    try {
        while ((lastInput = Input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(lastInput);
            if (lastInput.startsWith("Chat: ")) {
                sendToAllClients(lastInput.substring(7));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        disconnect();
    }
}
```

The Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at Main.User.run(User.java:46)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Note: the Username = Input.readLine() is making the Exception

Comment: You shouldn't be swallowing exceptions like that...

Comment: I'm not sure why you are trying to process the `lastInput` within the exception handler...

Answer (score 1):

To avoid your infinite loop and therefore your OOM exception:

```
try{
  while ((currentInput=Input.readLine()) != null) {
     if (currentInput.startsWith("Chat: "))
       sendToAllClients(currentInput.substring(7));
  }
catch (IOException e) { //bad to swallow exception:  let's the method throw it or make something with it here}
```

Answer (score 0):

readLine() does not create threads.

If 'lastInput' is null you should exit the loop and close the stream.

And if you get an exception, log it or print it, close the stream, and break.

Comment: the loop is to get all the Inputs from the Client when its sent to the server. so it just prints it. and the problem is not that loop, its get Username = Input.readLine()

Comment: When readLine() returns null there *is* no more input. Ever again. You could always try it, instead of arguing pointlessly. If your code was perfect you wouldn't have to ask the question.

Answer (score -1):

`Out of memory heap space`  comes into picture is the program is going in an infinite loop.

Your code :

```
 while (true) {
        try {
            lastInput = Input.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        if (lastInput != null) {
            System.out.println(lastInput);
            if (lastInput.startsWith("Chat: ")) {
                sendToAllClients(lastInput.substring(7));
            }
        }
```

says that the code inside the loop will run infinite many times without any condition acting as an exit condition. Even when an issue is coming : you are catching that exception and the code keeps on continuing inside the loop.

This leads to `Out of Memory : Heap Space.`

Suggesed solution :

```
while (true) 
{
    try 
    {
        lastInput = Input.readLine();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
     break;
    }
    if (lastInput != null) 
        {
           System.out.println(lastInput);
            if (lastInput.startsWith("Chat: ")) 
            {
            sendToAllClients(lastInput.substring(7));
            }
        }
}
```

This loop would break as soon user enters any name that causes an exception(which actually acts as an exit condition foe the while loop)

**EDIT**

One area which I see could be the source of the issue could be :

```
lastInput.substring(7)
```

If the `lastInput` string is of huge size that could almost fill up the `heap space of the JVM` installed on the system, then calling a `substring` from the `7th character to the last character`, would internally trigger the creation of new `String` (as Strings are immutable), & with not enough heap space left, `substring` execution gives an `OutOfMemory exception`.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think the infinite loop is trying to keep the program alive to act like a server.

Comment: I Changed the while loop, but the Username get is the line making the Exception.

Comment: This code must break out if the loop if readLine() returns null. Otherwise it is useless. -1

Answer (score -1):

first: check the loop of while of your program.
second: set the parameter set JAVA_OPTS= -Xms32m -Xmx512m.

Comment: i set the Xms and Xmx, hoping it would fix it already. its the Username = Input.readLine() making the exception, which is not in the while loop

Comment: Check the while loop how?